# Laravel: can't iterate through array of objects from json

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

When user clicks on icon, ajax call to controller is called and controller returns some comments.

My controller

```
public function read($id)
{
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id', $id)->get();

    return response()->json([
        'html' => view('includes.comments')->render(),
        'comments' => $comments
    ]);
}
```

Ajax succes function

```
var comments_box = comments_container.find('.comments-box');
comments_box.html(data.html);
console.log(data);
```

In console log there is an array of objects with comments and rendered html view. But I can't iterate through that array. If i put some garbage code in comments.blade.php it shows it. But if I try
`@foreach($comments as $comment) some code @endforeach` It can't work at all, error message is Undefined variable: comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass the variable to the view (if you want to use that variable in the blade file)

for example by saying

```
return view('includes.comments', ['comments' => $comments]);
```

that way the $comments variable will be available in the blade file and you can then use the `@foreach`

more on views [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views)

Answer (score 1):

I believe instead of:

```
return response()->json([
    'html' => view('includes.comments')->render(),
    'comments' => $comments
]);
```

you should rather use:

```
return response()->json([
    'html' => view('includes.comments', ['comments' => $comments])->render(),
    'comments' => $comments // this line might be not necessary
]);
```

This is because you want to render blade and you need to pass `$comments` into view. So depending on what you really want to return as json line:

```
'comments' => $comments // this line might be not necessary
```

might be completely not necessary in case you wanted to use it for view.